# Specialized calculator using VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have to project a specialized calculator on a Basys3 board using VHDL. The calculator should be able to group numbers using brackets, perform additions and substractions, AND and OR operations. For example, an expression could be: 4 + 5 AND 6 +(7 OR 1) - (4 AND 10)

The input numbers are 4 bit numbers (in my code I used 5 bit numbers, the most significant bit being the sign bit) and the output can be max. 16 bits long (i used 17 bits in my code, the most significant being the sign bit).

I wrote the code for the ALU (the adder/substractor, AND/OR) and I managed to make the calculator work for 2 numbers as inputs(using 2 in ports). This is the "main" code for the calculator, that i have written:

```
library IEEE;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;

entity calculator is
 port(X: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);    -- X(4) sign 
    Y: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);
    OPERATIE: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);
    CLK, CLR: in STD_LOGIC;
    a_to_g: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 downto 0);
    an: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    negativ: out std_logic);
end calculator;

architecture calculator of calculator is

component ALU is
    port(A,B: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(16 downto 0);
    COMANDA: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);
    RESULT: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(16 downto 0));
end component;

component BCD_7seg is
    port(X: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    CLK, CLR: in STD_LOGIC;
    a_to_g: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 downto 0);
    an: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0));
end component;

signal OPERAND_1: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(16 downto 0) := (others => '0');   
signal OPERAND_2: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(16 downto 0) := (others => '0');   
signal TEMP_RESULT: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(16 downto 0) := (others => '0'); 

begin  
    operand_1(3 downto 0) <= x(3 downto 0);
    operand_1(16) <= x(4);

    operand_2(3 downto 0) <= y(3 downto 0);
    operand_2(16) <= y(4);

    calculate: ALU port map(operand_1, operand_2, operatie, temp_result);

    afis: BCD_7seg port map(temp_result(15 downto 0), clk, clr, a_to_g, an);
    negativ <= temp_result(16);
end calculator;
```

However, the calculator should work for N numbers as inputs (using only one in port) and I don't know how to do it. I thought about memorising the whole expression(operartors and operands) in a FIFO or LIFO memory (but I'm not sure if that could work) and then making the calculations but I don't know how to calculate everything in the correct order given by the priorities and where(and how) to memorise the temporary results.

I thought that maybe you could give me some ideas, I'm new to VHDL, I'm a student and I have just started learning it and got stuck at this part in the project.

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO it is better to ask such a question on [Electrical Engineering StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: ...and my answer there would be that you will require some kind of scheduler. I would suggest looking at a [Stack machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine) architecture.

Comment: Des whole project has to be  in HDL? Because you could use VHDL entity just for inputs and outputs, and pass data for to some soft core, for example Microblaze, and parse it in c.

Comment: Thx for your replys, yes, the whole project has to be in VHDL.

Comment: how do you parse the brackets and the operators? that is not stated in you question. You just mention the 5-bit signed values

Comment: By codifying them in binary and using another in port. But one of the problems that I have is that I don't know how to memorise them.

Comment: You cannot do it without some kind of interpreter. Some level of reordering is required. Ask it on EE-SE ;)